# Find the multiplicative inverse of $x^4+x^3+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^5+x^2+1 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

*Find the multiplicative inverse of $x^4+x^3+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^5+x^2+1 \rangle$.*

What I've tried is as follows:

We know $\alpha^5+\alpha^2+1=0$. Then $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+1=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=\alpha^2(\alpha^2+1)(\alpha+1)$.

From $\alpha^5+\alpha^2+1=0$ we have, $\alpha^2(\alpha^3+1)=1$, so now we know the multiplicative inverse of $\alpha^2$, but we had no success finding the inverse of $\alpha^2+1$ nor $\alpha+1$. All of this was to avoid writing $q(x)$ as a general polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^5+x^2+1 \rangle$ and then solving that equation.

Are we on the right track? Is there any better approach? Thanks in advance for any help and any advice will be welcomed.

Comment: A brute force approach would be: for $p(x) = x^4 + x^3 + 1$, write $p(x), x p(x), \ldots, x^4 p(x)$ each in the form $\alpha x^4 + \beta x^3 + \gamma x^2 + \delta x + \epsilon$; and then, use linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$ to find a linear combination of these which is equal to 1.

Comment: Less brute force: use Euclid's algorithm to calculate the gcd of $x^4 + x^3 + 1$ and $x^5 + x^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ (hopefully finding 1 as the result) and then write $1 = p(x) (x^4 + x^3 + 1) + q(x) (x^5 + x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: The inverse of any $\beta$ in that field is $\beta^{30}$ which can be found by [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and is simple in characteristic $2$.

Comment: When you wrote $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$, did you mean $\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2$?